# Apply random color to each path without new function for each

Tags: javascript, svg, random

I have an SVG with a bunch of paths (`rect` here for simplicity)

```
<rect id=1 x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
<rect id=2 x="120" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
<rect id=3 x="240" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
```

I have my snippet which defines my colors:

```
var colors = ['red','yellow','green','blue','orange','purple','black','white'];
```

Then comes the snippet which randomizes the color

```
var random_color1 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
var random_color2 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
var random_color3 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

Then I have this which applies the random color to each path (each has a unique id)

```
document.getElementById('1').style.fill = random_color1;
document.getElementById('2').style.fill = random_color2;
document.getElementById('3').style.fill = random_color3;
```

---

The thing is, I have a few hundred paths in this document. I need to apply the randomize to each and every path, my current process leaves hundreds of lines of code.

I'm looking for a way to;

1. Not need a unique path id for each path
2. Call the `random_color` function each time for a path without creating a new one per path and then apply it to that path.

I'm really new to javascript and I've tried whatever I know, but to no avail.

Comment: As an aside, the first character of an id should not be numeric. Numeric ids can't be matched by CSS for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Not need a unique path id for each path

You'll need some sort of CSS selector that will match all of the paths (and nothing else). I've provided a very simple one, which is about all I can do at this point because you haven't elaborated further on how these paths are located within your HTML document.

> 2. Call the random_color function each time for a path without creating a new one per path and then apply it to that path.

Once you've solved #1, this is easy - select them all, iterate through them, and assign a random color to each.

```js
var colors = ['red','yellow','green','blue','orange','purple','black','white'];

var allPaths = document.querySelectorAll('svg rect');

allPaths.forEach(function (path) {
    path.style.fill = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
});
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect x="120" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
  <rect x="240" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can also pop the color. Make no-repeat on color. allPaths.forEach(function (path) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  const color = colors[index];
  colors.splice(index, 1);
  path.style.fill = colors[color];
});

Comment: @xdeepakv Apparently they're doing this to 100 elements, and I'm guessing they don't have 100 different colors prepared, so I would imagine they would allow repeats, but thanks.